# kubernetes ClusterIP service not able to route requests to containers on other nodes

Tags: networking, service, kubernetes

We have 3 physical machines installed with Kubernetes on Centos 7. We are using one machine as both master and worker and the other 2 machines are used as workers.

I have a service as defined below.

```
kubectl get service hostnames -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-01-08T21:26:54Z
  name: hostnames
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1209904"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/hostnames
  uid: 2d6b6ffe-d5e9-11e6-b2d8-842b2b55e882
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.254.241.39
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app: hostnames
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Trying to invoke the service is working only when the request is routed to the container that is physically on the same machine.

```
[root@server5 hostnames]# curl 10.254.241.39:80
^C
[root@server5 hostnames]# curl 10.254.241.39:80
hostnames-9ga5b
[root@server5 hostnames]# curl 10.254.241.39:80
hostnames-9ga5b
[root@server5 hostnames]# curl 10.254.241.39:80
```

The endpoints exist and invoking the endpoint IP Address directly works.

```
server5 hostnames]# curl 10.20.36.4:9376; curl 10.20.48.6:9376; curl 10.20.63.2:9376
hostnames-9ga5b
hostnames-ygxnk
hostnames-vcfql
```

The IP Tables rules are created by kube-proxy as shown below.

```
server5 hostnames]# iptables-save | grep hostnames
-A KUBE-SEP-3UQOVTFJM332BGMS -s 10.20.48.6/32 -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-3UQOVTFJM332BGMS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.48.6:9376
-A KUBE-SEP-6ZUKVGLXRG6BMNNI -s 10.20.63.2/32 -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-6ZUKVGLXRG6BMNNI -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.63.2:9376
-A KUBE-SEP-UMK676VFQ5WVT4CI -s 10.20.36.4/32 -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-UMK676VFQ5WVT4CI -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.36.4:9376
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.241.39/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hostnames: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-NWV5X2332I4OT4T3
-A KUBE-SVC-NWV5X2332I4OT4T3 -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.33332999982 -j KUBE-SEP-UMK676VFQ5WVT4CI
-A KUBE-SVC-NWV5X2332I4OT4T3 -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-3UQOVTFJM332BGMS
-A KUBE-SVC-NWV5X2332I4OT4T3 -m comment --comment "default/hostnames:" -j KUBE-SEP-6ZUKVGLXRG6BMNNI
```

Checking the logs of kube-proxy does not show any errors. Increase the logging level using -v 4.

We checked the behavior above on the other 2 machines and is identical (IP tables rules, being able to route the requests of the service only to local container, end points being reachable directly with the container IP address).

Is there a reason kubernetes service is not able to route the requests to containers running on other physical machines? The firewall on all machines is disabled and stopped.

Thanks.

Comment: What SDN are you using Flannel? I've had these issues when my network overlay is not properly configured.

Comment: Yes, using flannel. Here is the configuration in flannel i currently have. I am able reach the containers on a different physical machine using it's IP Address though

`# Flanneld configuration options

# etcd url location.  Point this to the server where etcd runs
#FLANNEL_ETCD_ENDPOINTS="http://127.0.0.1:2379"
FLANNEL_ETCD_ENDPOINTS="http://192.168.90.233:2379"

# etcd config key.  This is the configuration key that flannel queries
# For address range assignment
FLANNEL_ETCD_PREFIX="/atomic.io/network"

# Any additional options that you want to pass
#FLANNEL_OPTIONS=""
 `

Comment: Does `curl`ing the `clusterIP` work on only the controller (that resolves only to itself) or on all nodes? If it only works on the controller, it is possible that there is an auth issue between the nodes and the master. Check if you can connect to the controller and use `kubectl` when logged on into one of the nodes.